# Need to override the spring boot version used by jhipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I am using jhipster version 3.0.6 which uses spring boot version 2.1.9 release.
I need to override this spring boot version to 2.3.3 Release.
Is there any way to do it? I added below property in my project's pom xml , inside the properties section.

```
 <spring-boot.version>2.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

But looks like, this is ignored and  'spring boot version 2.1.9 release' is being used which is configured in jhipster.
is there any way to override this spring boot version?

Comment: You cannot just override the spring boot version, as things will break. Spring Boot 2.1 uses Spring 5.1 whereas Spring Boot 2.3 uses 5.2 with a lot of changes not to mention all other supporting libraries.

Comment: But if I make sure to override versions of all the dependencies in a way that they will work in sync, how can I achieve it? the basic problem that I am facing is, I can not override the versions in my project which are originally defined in jhipster's parent pom

Comment: Which might break the jhipster generated code. Upgrade jHipster instead.

Comment: You can't just update from 2.1x to 2.3.x as there are breaking changes in spring boot itself which requires changes in your code. So the best way would be to upgrade to jhipster 6.10 which already supports boot 2.2.x. The update to 2.3.x will come with jhipster 7 sadly, but the upgrade from 2.2.x to 2.3.x for a generated project should be possible.

Comment: The suggestions above are correct in the context of upgrading from 2.1. to 2.3. However, this simple task is made more difficult because of the way jhipster-dependencies is made, personally I completely  got rid of  jhipster-dependencies to manage myself the versions using mainly spring boot starters. I reported this difficulty but I  was not convincing enough to make a change, https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/12019

Comment: I agree. Maybe we should revisit that during jhipster code.

Comment: I think it should be possible to override versions in generated applications. Otherwise, what's the point of specifying the version number in the build file?